# JAX-RS webservice testcase Injection of EntityManager sets NULL object in TestClass

Tags: unit-testing, jax-rs, wildfly-9, hibernate-entitymanager

I am beginner with JAX-RS webservice and its testcase.

My TestController class is as follows:

```
public class LotTypeMangementServiceTest {

private final String LOT_NAME = "lotName";

@Inject
private LotTypeManagementService lotTypeService;

@Test
private LotType testCreate() {
    LotType newLotType = new LotType();
    newLotType.setName(LOT_NAME);
    
    //save
    lotTypeService.createOrUpdate(newLotType);
    
    Assert.assertNotNull(newLotType.getId());
    
    return newLotType;
  }
}
```

My LotTypeManagementService as follows:

```
@Stateless
public class LotTypeManagementService {
        
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="primary")
    private EntityManager em;
    
    public void createOrUpdate(LotType lotType) {
        if (lotType.getId() == null) { // Save New Label Type
            em.persist(lotType);
        } else {    // Update Label Type
            em.merge(lotType);
        }
    }
}
```

Now as you can see, `LotTypeManagementService` has `EntityManager` dependency.

In testclass, I've injected `LotTypeManagementService`. However, its dependency is not getting injected and hence I `em` object is `NULL`.

My persistence.xml file is as below:

```
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
   
   <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/lottype</jta-data-source>
  
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      </properties> 
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My RestController is as below:

```
@RequestScoped
public class LotTypeResourceRESTService {

    @Inject
    private LotTypeManagementService lotTypeService;
}
```

I am using wildfly-9.0.1 server, java8, JAX-RS webservice, hibernate,  jpa-2.1 and jUnit.

I found some solution on Stack Overflow like

1. Use `@Inject` or `@Ejb`
2. some change on persistance.xml `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>`
3. `em = (EntityManager) new nitialContext().lookup("java:/primary");`
4. Like create dynamically container.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: What does the test environment look like? For example how are you starting WildFly, deploying your test app, executing the test methods, etc.

Comment: I am running TestCase using RunAs -> Junit Test

Comment: AFAIK JUnit doesn't know how to inject anything especially EJB's. You really need to use something like Arquillian if you want to do in container testing.